# Can ReferenceEquals with strings be reliably used to detect a sentinel value?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a third party .NET DLL with a function that returns a string and includes a string parameter named *sentinel*, documented as...

> If (condition) occurs, the function will return the string supplied as the parameter *sentinel*. The code will not make use of this parameter in any other circumstances. This condition may be tested for by using *Object.ReferenceEquals* on the value returned. Do not use == to test for the sentinel value as the loaded string may coincidentally have the same text value. Do not supply *null* as the sentinel as the function will return *null* when (reasons) and two different nulls cannot be distinguished.

Is this mechanism reliable in .NET? The third party can only control what code goes into it's own DLL and can't control what the run-time does.

If I supply a string object created by new string('x',1) as the sentinel and the library reads an "x", can I be sure .NET will never save the extra reference and reuse this other string object it found lying around?

(I acknowledge there are better ways to do this, but that's beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: Looks like a terribly bad designed third party API. `string` is the worst possible data type to use for a true/false scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the *sentinel* value gets provided.

In general, a runtime generated `string` will be unique, and keep a single unique instance.  However, if a constant is used, it will be interned, and it's possible any other constant with the same value will be the same reference due to string interning.

That being said, using a value as a sentinel that should be truly unique (such as a guid) seems like a better and safer approach overall.  Given that it's third party and you can't change it, if you provide the sentinel value, I would recommend using a string vaule where the method of comparison won't matter (ie: make sure it's a real, unique string).